# How to define an interface from another interface

Tags: c#

I have this generic  interface

```
interface Iinterface1<A>{

   A getposition(int i);
}
```

I would like to create another interface, exactly the same as interface1 but with the constraint that A implement Comparable A>.

For Comparable alone (without A>), It seems to works.

```
    interface interface2 :interface1 <IComparable>{};
```

But not for Comparable:

```
    interface interface2 :interface1<IComparable<A>
```

> the type or namespace A could not be found.

```
interface interface2 :interface1<A> where  A:IComparable<A>
```

> Constraint are not allowed in non-generic declaration

And Really want to use Comparable instead of Comparable; I only want to compare similar things

Comment: `A` is a generic parameter; it has to come from *somewhere*, and if `interface2` is not generic it can't come from anywhere. Either make it a parameter (`interface2<A>`), or specify an actual type name (`interface1<IComparable<MyClass>>`). Perhaps make your example less general and clarify what exactly it is you're trying to achieve on a concrete level.

Comment: `interface interface2<A> : interface1<A> where A : IComparable<A>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to make the interface generic also:

```
interface interface2<A> :interface1<A> where  A:IComparable<A>
```